# Visual Studio: Show const value in tooltip

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

I recently down- and upgraded my Visual Studio installation from 2015 enterprise to 2017 community.

In a c# file I have some const values:

```
const float PI = 3.14159f;
const float HALF_PI = PI/2.f;
```

In vs2015, when I hovered my mouse over HALF_PI (with no debugging process running), the tooltip would show me the actual value of HALF_PI ("1.57.."), while in vs2017 it shows me "PI/2.f".

It might have been an extension I installed (I use re#, but on vs2015 im pretty sure I had some other extensions installed, not sure, which though :/ ) or some kind of setting, that I can't find now.

How could I regain that behaviour?

---

**SOLUTION:**
In Resharper Options

*Code Inspection -> Settings*

Enable *Color identifiers*

Now it's working for me "as intended", allthough I still have NO IDEA, how color identifiers have anything to do with that particular issue :)

Comment: I think it's CodeLens which isn't in the Community version.

Comment: Quite possible... Is there any (free) extension that emulates CodeLens (or at least that behaviour?)

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a comment, but posting as Answer to include an image.

One useful way, I normally do is to have a comment using "///". This will show up as tool tip.

Example screen shot:
[image: Comment as tool tip]

Comment: thank you for this suggestion. This works perfectly for a const like PI that wont ever change its value. But on real application settings, that you actually want to change in between compilations, thats not really feasible.